How to manage canonical URLs for multiple domains with identical content to avoid SEO penalties?
I am managing a website that has several country-specific domains (e.g., .com, .be, .nl, .fr), but all of these domains load the exact same content. The primary version of the website is the .com domain, while the others are used to cater to different regions.
Currently, each domain has its own canonical URL pointing to itself, which has resulted in duplicate content issues and links being flagged as toxic by SEO tools. I want to avoid this problem while still keeping all the domains live without redirecting them to the .com site.
Temporary solution we're considering: We are thinking of setting all canonical URLs on each domain (e.g., .be, .nl, .fr) to point to the equivalent .com version of the page. For example, the canonical URL for www.site.be/nl/page would point to www.site.com/nl/page.
My questions:

Should I point all the canonical URLs on each domain to the .com version, even though they are hosted on different domains?
Will this prevent the .be, .nl, and .fr versions from being indexed by search engines?
Is there a way to balance keeping multiple domains live while preventing SEO penalties for duplicate content?

Any advice on the best approach for this situation would be appreciated.

You should be looking at rel="alternate".  Canonical tells Google that you only want one version indexed, whereas this tag says which version should be shown in which region.
Google say you should use this when:

If your content has small regional variations with similar content, in
a single language.

or

If your site content is fully translated into multiple languages.

I assume one of these applies to you.

I agree that alternate hreflang is how you tell Google which regional pages to show to people in the regions.
Google will probably canonicalise the duplicate versions to one of the duplicates. This is not an issue. Google only needs to index one copy, then the hreflang settings tell it which copy to show.
You could canonicalize all to the .com to encourage Google to use that domain for the indexing.

They don't state so, but I'm assuming they want the local URLs to appear in localised searches?  Otherwise they may need to explain why they don't just want to redirect the domains.

@RichardB Yes, it is indeed important for us to appear in localized searches. That’s the main reason we don’t want to use a simple 301 redirect to the .com version. We're aiming to keep the local URLs visible in search results for their respective regions while managing the duplicate content issue effectively.

So use hreflang. Redirects will force everything to one domain.

So just to confirm, on each page, we would use the .com as the canonical, like this: <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.site.com/page.html" /> And for the .be version, we would add: <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-be" href="https://www.site.be/nl/page.html" /> and <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-be" href="https://www.site.be/fr/page.html" /> for the .be version? Am I understanding this correctly? And for the .fr, .nl, and other domains, we must repeat this setup as well, right?
